# Extremely slow login after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, login, xubuntu

I just upgraded my xubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and now, when I login into the GUI, I have to wait about 3 minutes before the desktop appears. Only the background image is displayed. 
The login into the console works fine (with ctrl+alt+f2)

Even stranger: 
If I login first in the console and then in the GUI, it boots quickly. 
 If I login first in the GUI, switch to console and login, it takes 3 minutes to boot in the GUI.

My machine is a thinkpad T420s.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where logging in would show just the wallpaper for about 40 seconds before showing anything else, but subsequent logins were fast until the next reboot. I also had the same behaviour where logging in to a terminal first would make the graphical login fast, so it was a once-per-boot thing.

I changed a few things in trying to solve it but the probable culprits were either disabling IPv6, or disabling the couchdb service. IPv6 is something I'm not going to be able to use any time in the near future, and couchdb is something I installed a while ago and really doesn't need to be running all the time. In any case, the time from entering my password to having a usable desktop is now a couple of seconds.

If science demanded it I could always go back and narrow down which one caused the slowdown, but I'd try the IPv6 thing first and then see if any optional services are starting (you could try using [BootChart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting) to log your startup and spot any nonessential processes that take a long time).

Comment: I have the same issue. Upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 to 12.04. I suffer from this issue every time I log in into any account that has never been logged in since this boot. (that means, after a very long period of waiting to log in on a user `foo`, switching to another user `bar` takes long time too (which, theoretically, should not happen if is caused by IPv6 service.

Answer (score 0):

could be some legacy setting which is conflicting, if you log in as another user (preferably created after the upgrade) do you get the same problems?

if not. reboot your computer into fail safe mode.
rename your home folder to .old or something and create a new home folder.
don't forget to set the correct permissions for it.
Compare to the old folder preferably.

I would move stuff in increments into the newly created home folder from the old one until i find  which old config there is messing with things.

or you can just choose to start over with your new fresh settings.

Comment: In my case, no. A newly-added user also suffers from long-desktop-loading time first time he/she logs into the machine since it last boot.